# Change emulated front camera image?

Tags: android, android-camera

There is a way i can change the default image for the emulated front camera in the avd settings?

The closest infos i found are regarding the rear camera with the virtual scene, here's a link: https://gist.github.com/gabrieljoelc/df8256b896cac46bd51fd2deb412da5f

Do you know how to load images to the emulated front camera within android studio or maybe via adb shell?